# Facebook Log In flutter, get user ID

Tags: facebook, firebase, flutter

I'm trying to get the facebook friends of my new users (to recommend them friends). I did all the work: integrated facebook in the app, permission facebook etc.

Then I use this to get the users

```
curl -i -X GET \
 "https://graph.facebook.com/v4.0/ i put the user id here }?fields=id%2Cfriends&access_token= my acces token"
```

It works, but there's a problem with the id's:

If i use the facebook graph API: it says my ID is : 23337 ... (only digits).

If i log in with facebook in the flutter app: my ID is: M670V ... (digits + (capital) letters )

Only the id with only digits works for the curl.
How can I get the id with only digits from the flutter facebook sing in?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of research,

The id with digits + letters is the firebase ID, it differs from the real facebook id.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: i get same problem, how can resolve what change required please help

Answer (score 3):

In login with facebook using firebase authentication, the **uid** is the firebase id so if you need facebook userId the call one api for get.

```
var graphResponse = await http.get(
'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.12/me? 
fields=name,first_name,last_name,email&access_token=${facebookLoginResult
.accessToken.token}');

var profile = json.decode(graphResponse.body);
print(profile.toString());
//it return detail of facebook user
```

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/